# using IF conditional in mysqli select statements

Tags: php

i am currently building a hostel management system and i have a problem when it comes to the selection of rooms which i have already selected from the database and built a select box...the problem is , i want my php script to only allow a maximum number of students per room..eg if room one can only hold 4 students ,then only 4 can be allowed into the room via the admin form that i have built...here is my code..
after basic form validation...

```
$q="SELECT IF(Space >=1, 'true', 'false'),FROM rooms WHERE Room_id=$room_id";
$r=mysqli_query($con, $q);

 if($r==true){

   $q=INSERT INTO students(first_name, last_name, room_id)VALUES('$fn',   '$ln', '$room_id')";
$p=mysqli_query($con, $q)

  or die("Error querying database");

if($p){

$u="UPDATE rooms SET Space=(Space -1) WHERE Room_id=$room_id LIMIT 1";
}
}elseif($r==false){
  echo'<p>That room is already full please select another room</p>';
}
```

the problem is the insert query is being performed even when the space is less than 1 and update is running until the integer value(which is the data type that i used in building the space column in the rooms table), is negative and the php script is allowing insert queries into the database even if space is less than 1....
here is an example of my rooms table..

```
CREATE TABLE rooms(Room_id TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Wing VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Space INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Room_id));
```

NB :Space column is what determines the number of people that each room can hold...

Ihave a separate table that holds the students details...
All responses will be greatly appreciated

Comment: First of all, please make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(Space >=1, 'true', 'false') as column_name FROM rooms WHERE Room_id=$room_id
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking mysql result ref, query result, you should use `mysqli_fetch_row()` to see query result, see sample code below

```
$q="SELECT IF(Space >=1, true, false) AS `space_bool` FROM rooms WHERE Room_id=$room_id";
$r=mysqli_query($con, $q);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

if($row['space_bool'] == true){
...
....

}
```

other issue in query `IF-ELSE` assign into new result column (`space_bool`), this would easy to fetch row in PHP code

Comment: even after making the new changes to my script as you have recommended, there seems to be a problem with the selection of rooms because i keep on getting an echo message saying that a particular room is full yet in the rooms table that room is empty...Any recommendations?

Comment: i found an easy way of doing it, though i dont know whether its the best way, but here it is....i added a check constraint in the space column in my rooms table like this...alter table rooms add check(space > 0) .... so that after i run my update, there is no way that column will ever have a negative value..